# Search SQL JSON array of objects

Tags: json, sql-server

I have a SQL column that contains JSON such as this

```
{
"tags":[
{"id":11,"x":99.12343123213,"y":88.123232},
{"id":12,"x":99.12343123213,"y":88.123232},
{"id":13,"x":99.12343123213,"y":88.123232}
]
}
```

I am trying to find a record with the value of '13', however the number of objects may vary. I know that i could use code similar to:

```
select * from Logs WHERE JSON_VALUE([log],'$.tags[0].id') LIKE '13'
```

Unfortunately, the number of objects in the array could be any number. How could I search through every object in my array for the value?

I am aware I could search through the string for the value of '%"id":13,%', however this seems like a messy solution.

Comment: What variety of SQL are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2017

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`OPENJSON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to extract the `id` values from your JSON objects and `CROSS APPLY` that to your `logs` table, selecting only rows that have an `id` value in the JSON object of 13:

```
SELECT logs.*
FROM logs
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON([log], '$.tags') WITH (id INT '$.id')
WHERE id = 13
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=9a6a689f9cc38cde6a36f813af24a343)

Comment: how can I use this for mariadb?

Comment: This is SQL server specific. I suggest asking a new question as the solution would be quite different for MariaDB